# How can I have two .NET projects in the same domain

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0

I have two .NET projects in the same domain. The first project I create long time ago in VB.NET. Now I create another project that I built in C#. How can I set up my new project in the same domain so I can access the new forms that I built in C#. Do I need to submit the whole folder from the project? Do I need to change anything in the web.config? Right now I am getting this error. [PhoneControl] is the new project in C#.
http://www.martinesexpress-inc.com/PhoneControl/Default.aspx

Comment: turn on errors for remote computers in your web.config so we can see why it fails.

Comment: better yet, paste us the error so it doesn't go away and invalidate this question.

Comment: You mean this?

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Quick question can I keep both web.congfigs. One for my vb and the one for my c#?

Comment: FYI. I don't get this error in my local machine. I already create the <customErrors mode="Off"/> in the web.config but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the error page it says:

[alt text http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5868/capturevv.png](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5868/capturevv.png)

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2407; 
ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2407
```

And you are trying to use some .NET 3.5 components

Change the website to use .Net 2.0 and **make sure the server have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed**

If you are using IIS6:
[alt text http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/1410/capture2s.png](http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/1410/capture2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the language correctly in your page?